# When building Go programs for release is it standard practice to just use 'go build'?

Tags: go, compilation, release

When building Go programs for release is it standard practise to just use `go build` without any other options? I ask because when building using `go build` all debug information is included by default. To remove it you can pass an option to the linker, thus:

```
go build -ldflags "-w" prog.go
```

This omits all debug symbols. When building programs for release do you remove this information or leave it intact?

EDIT: For clarity, i'm wondering how people compile Go programs for deployment to a live environment. In other compiled languages you have a different set of compiler command line options for debugging and release builds and release builds usually optimise the executable and remove debugging information.

Comment: Removing debug information from a Go program may break certain uses of reflection. You should not use that flag.

Comment: Depending on your use case. For deployment to my own servers, which I'm guessing is how the overwhelming majority of Go users deploy - you really shouldn't do it. It gives you nothing really and prevents debugging on servers and some reflect stuff.

Comment: @FUZxxl What uses of reflection? All seems to work just fine. http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2woogl/when_building_go_programs_for_release_is_it/cot9q3z

Comment: Plain `go build` is the norm. It runs when you `go get` something; I hadn't known until today about `-ldflags -w`; Go's usual norm is not to complicate things for a little tuning; I doubt it'll make a huge difference (static linking is the big cause of big binaries); and reactions to stripping symbols seemed generally negative [on this golang-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/yzcYsnNiUgg).

Comment: [Going by this old thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Xr2Zsa0YfKs/auAlsnWf7-oJ) I think `-s` has to leave some data in for the runtime (so stripping doesn't even completely strip). Also, user davecheney on Reddit says it's standard practice to just use 'go build', and is one of the committers on the Go project, so believe him. :)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer nope, the norm in programming world is removing debug symbols for production environment.

Comment: @fuz where is reference of your claim about reflection?

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi It used to be that Go's reflection support used the ELF symbol table.  Hence you were [not supposed to strip Go binaries](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5855#issuecomment-66082174).  However, newer versions of Go store the required metadata in separate tables, making stripping binaries a supported option.

Comment: @fuz thank you, so it is safe for use in newer versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Dave Cheney](http://dave.cheney.net/about) the answer is yes, just use `go build`.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2woogl/when_building_go_programs_for_release_is_it/